# How can I assign values to a map < map<int,int> , bool >?

Tags: c++

How can I assign values to a map declaring like this?

```
map < map<int,int> , bool > Map;
```

I want code to look like this:

```
Map[u][v]=true;
```

Where `u` or `v` can be maximum `10^5`.

How can I code this?

Comment: If those indexes are really integers **and** you don't care about ordering as much as access time, `std::unordered_map` will probably give you better performance. Just saying.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yep, `unordered_map` is faster. I'd also create a wrapper class, tack u and v in two 32 bit words to make a 64 bit word then use a single unordered_map<int64_t, bool> About twice as fast since there is only one hash per lookup

Answer (score 4):

what you want is:

```
std::map<int, std::map<int, bool> > myMap;
```

Then you can set/get values by:

```
bool myBool;
myMap[u][v] = myBool;
myBool = myMap[u][v];
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no need for the ordering behavior of `map` as @WhozCraig noted in a comment then `unordered_map` is a much faster choice.

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int, bool> > myMap;
```

However, wrapping a single `unordered_map` with a helper class will typically halve the execution time since only one hash needs to be done to look up the two integers.

```
class Map2ints
{
    class Map2Helper {
        int u;
        std::unordered_map<int64_t, bool> &vmap;
    public:
        bool& operator[](int v) { return vmap[u | (static_cast<int64_t>(v) << 32)]; }
        Map2Helper(int u, std::unordered_map<int64_t, bool> &vmap) :u(u), vmap(vmap) {}
    };
    std::unordered_map<int64_t, bool> vmap;
    bool contains(int u, int v) { return vmap.find(u | (static_cast<int64_t>(v) << 32))!=vmap.end(); }
public:
    Map2Helper operator[](int u) { return Map2Helper{ u, vmap }; }
};
```

Then the usage would be the same. For instance:

```
Map2ints myMap;
myMap[70000][151] = true;
bool a = myMap[70000][151];  // which sets a to true
```